# ng2-translate customLoader & multiple files per language

Tags: ionic2, rxjs, observable, ng2-translate

In an Ionic2 app I'm using ng2-translate the strings in my app.

Now I need to split the translation file into several files per language, for example `de.json` and `de_gs1ais.json`. As ng2-translate is limited to one file per language I've tried to implement a custom loader:

```ts
class CustomLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  private http: Http;
  public getTranslation(lang: String): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("assets/i18n" + "/" + lang + ".json").map((res) => res.json());

  }
}
```

This class implements the standard ng2-translate behaviour, while with the following class I'd expect the 2 files `de.json` and `de_gs1ais.json` to be loaded:

```ts
class CustomLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  private http: Http;
  public getTranslation(lang: String): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("assets/i18n" + "/" + lang + ".json").merge(
    this.http.get("assets/i18n" + "/" + lang + "_gs1ais.json")).map((res) => res.json());

  }
}
```

The problem is that again only the first file (`de.json`) is loaded. Changing the order of the observables in the codes results in the other file being loaded.
I thought "merge" should merge together the observables, creating one "big" observable stream with all the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a forkJoin instead of the merge.

Merge doesn't combine data - https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html

forkJoin does - https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

```js
public getTranslation(lang: String): Observable<any> {
  let languageObservables = Rx.Observable.forkJoin(              
    this.http.get("assets/i18n" + "/" + lang + ".json"),
    this.http.get("assets/i18n" + "/" + lang + "_gs1ais.json")
  );
  return languageObservables.map((res) => res.json())
}
```